# Is there any way to debug my winform application on a Microsoft surface simulator using Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008, simulator

I have an outlook VSTO add in, developed using winform application for .net framework 3.5. It works fine on normal PCs for windows 10.But the UI gets distorted when people run it on Microsoft Surface. e.g the tree view nodes overlap each other.So, Is there ant surface simulator like those for IOS and android, on which I can debug my application using Visual Studio?

Comment: The Surface runs a standard OS so a simulator should not be necessary. Is the tree control a third-party control? What version of Outlook are you running on the Surface and is it the same as your PC? Because the Surface is a touch-enabled device could the .NET version or control itself be incorrect for use in the Surface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the problem was of resolution.The surface was running 2000*3000 resolution and my winform application wasn't resolution independent.As in winform you can't specify size and location in percentages.So, I just made all my UI elements position relative to each other rather that giving them a fixed location.